# how to override the update method of a model in django

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am using django with python. I am trying to update the model whenever a field is updated, in this case because i have a lambda function in the cloud, i want when a postgres query update an instance of the model, during the update action, update the age of the Person model below:

## data

Contact table

id = 1

name = 'john'

age = 38

## sql

```
UPDATE contacts_contact SET name = 'jane' where id = '1';   # this works fine
```

now i want to make sure that when the name is changed to `jane` as above, that the age update automatically in django with the override method

## django

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ..
    name = models.CharField()
    age = models.IntegerField()

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.age:
            self.age = 25
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)                     # i tried this
        super(Contact, self).update(*args, **kwargs)        # i tried this too
```

both update methods i tried above do not update the age of the person regardless of the fact that the sql query update worked

is there something that i am missing?

PS: I want to update that field specifically in django, not in the sql query

Comment: I hope you can try the `post_save` signals

Answer (score 0):

`"I am using django with python. I am trying to update the model whenever a field is updated"` if this is the case django signals can help you, in-fact they are built for this purpose only.

follow the below to steps to enable the django-signals for your models.

Inside your_app/app.py you can find the snippets as below. if not paste the same and modify it with your app name. here you're just importing the signals(contents in your_app/signal.py)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class YourAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'your_app'
    verbose_name = 'Your App'

    def ready(self):
        import your_app.signals
```

Inside your_app/signals.py paste the contents below in it. modify it with your own model name. for now I'll use your `Contact` model.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from your_app.models import Contact
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(post_save, sender=Contact)
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print(sender)
    print(instance)
    print(kwargs)
    if created:
        print('Hurray its created', created)
```

here you can use post_save signal. Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place.

whenever you call .save() method of Contact model(create/update). for example -

> c = Contact(name='zzz', age=20)

> c.save()

now this will make the post_save signal to get notified about the changes, you can verify the same in your create_user() method print statements. from here you can do whatever you want with your model.

you can refer more about post_save signals here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save

Comment: it doesnt seem to work, maybe because the update is triggered by the sql query update and django have no clue how to run the signal or update method since its not coming from django, i could be wrong but thats how i feel like